# Javascript - passing returned variable to another function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass my results value from to projectYears() function  to projectInvestment() function that will then write to the div tag. I am getting the error  "result is not defined error". To me this makes sense. All the code is working as intended. Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

```
function projectInvestment(nameId, investmentId, interestId, yearsId, amountId) {
    var inputName = document.getElementById(nameId).value;
    var inputInvestment = parseFloat(document.getElementById(investmentId).value);
    var inputInterest = parseFloat(document.getElementById(interestId).value);
    var inputYears = parseInt(document.getElementById(yearsId).value);
    var inputAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById(amountId).value);
    projectYears(inputInvestment, inputInterest, inputYears);
    var outputString = projectYears(result);
    document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = outputString;
}
function projectYears(inInvest, inInterest, inYears) {
    var interest = parseFloat(inInterest / 100);
    var interestAmt = parseFloat(inInvest * interest);
    var predictedInvest = parseFloat(inInvest + interestAmt);
    var result = "<br /> Investment Schedule for <b>$" + inInvest.toFixed(2) +
        " </b>at <b>" + inInterest + "% </b>annual interest for <b>" + inYears + "</b> years <br /><br />";
    result += "<table border='1' align='center'><tr><th>Year</th><th>Amount</th>";
    //for loop to loop through the years
    for (var x = 1; x <= inYears; x++) {
        result += "<tr><td>" + x + "</td><td>" + predictedInvest.toFixed(2) + "</td></tr>";
        interestAmt = predictedInvest * interest;
        predictedInvest = (predictedInvest + interestAmt);
    }
    result += "</table>";
    return result;
    //document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: try `var outputString =  projectYears(inputInvestment, inputInterest, inputYears); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in a variable called `result` that isn't defined.

See this line in the `projectInvestment` function:

```
var outputString =  projectYears(result);
```

It looks like, based on the function definition for `projectYears`, you should be passing in some of the variables you create above this line instead.

i.e.

```
var outputString = projectYears(inputInvestment, inputInterest, inputYears);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById(amountId).value);
var outputString = projectYears(inputInvestment, inputInterest, inputYears);
document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = outputString;
```